# Kafka transactional Producer and consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I'm working on kafka use case where I need to have transactional semantics on producer & consumer side..I'm able to publish transactional messages using kafka transaction API 0.11 to the kafka cluster but on consumer side I'm facing the issue...I have set `isolation.level=read_committed` in properties file But I'm not able to consume it..I could see messages being consumed with `isolation.level=read_uncommitted` but this is not desired..

producer code

```java
package com.org.kafkaPro;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.common.errors.OutOfOrderSequenceException;
import org.apache.kafka.common.errors.ProducerFencedException;

import kafka.common.AuthorizationException;
import kafka.common.KafkaException;

    public class ProducerWithTx
    {


        public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {
            URL in = ProducerWithTx.class.getResource("producertx.properties");

            Properties props = new Properties();

            try {
                props.load(new FileReader(new File(in.getFile())));
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }


            Paymnt pay1= new Paymnt();
            pay1.setAccid(1);
            pay1.setAccountstate("y");
            pay1.setAccountzipcode(111);
            pay1.setBankid(12);
            pay1.setCreditcardtype(15);
            pay1.setCustomerid("2");
            SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd");
            Date t = null;
            try {
                t = ft.parse("2017-11-10");
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            pay1.setPeriodid(t);

            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd:HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());
            props.put("transactional.id", "accid=" + pay1.getAccid() +  " custid=" +pay1.getCustomerid()+  " timestmp=" +timeStamp);
            KafkaProducer<String, Paymnt> producer = new KafkaProducer(props);
            producer.initTransactions();  
            try{
                producer.beginTransaction();



                //RecordMetadata metadata=producer.send((ProducerRecord<String, Paymnt>) new ProducerRecord<String, Paymnt>("test",pay1)).get();

                producer.send((ProducerRecord<String, Paymnt>) new ProducerRecord<String, Paymnt>("test",pay1));
                producer.commitTransaction();

                //System.out.println("written to" +metadata.partition());

            }
            catch (ProducerFencedException | OutOfOrderSequenceException | AuthorizationException  e){

                // We can't recover from these exceptions, so our only option is to close the producer and exit.
                producer.close();
            }
            catch(KafkaException e) {
                // For all other exceptions, just abort the transaction and try again.
                producer.abortTransaction();
            }
            producer.close();
        }

    }
```

producertx.properties

```
metadata.broker.list=localhost:9092
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
acks=all
retries=1
batch.size=16384
linger.ms=1
buffer.memory=33554432
key.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
value.serializer=com.org.kafkaPro.PaySerializer
#transactional.id=1
enable.idempotence=true
num.partitions=3
```

Consumer

```java
package com.org.kafkaPro;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Consumer {

    private static List<ConsumerMultiThreaded> consumersGroup;


    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {


        URL in = ProducerWithTx.class.getResource("consumer.properties");

        Properties props = new Properties();

        try {
            props.load(new FileReader(new File(in.getFile())));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        consumersGroup=new ArrayList<ConsumerMultiThreaded>();
        ConsumerMultiThreaded con1= new ConsumerMultiThreaded(props);
        ConsumerMultiThreaded con2=new ConsumerMultiThreaded(props);
        ConsumerMultiThreaded con3=new ConsumerMultiThreaded(props);
        ConsumerMultiThreaded con4=new ConsumerMultiThreaded(props);

        consumersGroup.add(con1);
        consumersGroup.add(con2);
        consumersGroup.add(con3);
        consumersGroup.add(con4);

        for (ConsumerMultiThreaded consumer : consumersGroup) {

            Thread t=new Thread(consumer);
            t.start();

        }

        while(true){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {

            }


        }
    }
}
```

Consumer Runnable

```java
public class ConsumerMultiThreaded implements Runnable {

private final AtomicBoolean closed = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    private final KafkaConsumer<String, Paymnt> consumer;
    private final int minBatchSize =3;
    private final List<ConsumerRecord<String, Paymnt>> buffer;


    public ConsumerMultiThreaded(Properties props){
        this.consumer= new KafkaConsumer<String, Paymnt>(props);
        buffer = new ArrayList(minBatchSize);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("test"));
            while (!closed.get()) {
                ConsumerRecords<String,Paymnt> records = consumer.poll(10000);

                for (ConsumerRecord<String, Paymnt> record : records) {
                    buffer.add(record);
                }

                /*for (ConsumerRecord<String, Paymnt> record : records)
                {
                    System.out.println("record consumed by Thread " +Thread.currentThread().getId() +" value is " +record.value().toString());
                }*/
                if(buffer.size()>=minBatchSize){
                    for (TopicPartition partition : records.partitions()) {
                        List<ConsumerRecord<String, Paymnt>> partitionRecords = records.records(partition);
                        for (ConsumerRecord<String, Paymnt> record : partitionRecords) {
                            System.out.println("record consumed by Thread " +Thread.currentThread().getId() +"from partition" +record.partition() +"offset" +record.offset() + "value: " + record.value().toString());
                        }
                        long lastOffset = partitionRecords.get(partitionRecords.size() - 1).offset();
                        consumer.commitSync(Collections.singletonMap(partition, new OffsetAndMetadata(lastOffset + 1)));
                        buffer.clear();
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (WakeupException e) {
            // Ignore exception if closing
            if (!closed.get()) throw e;
        } 
        finally {
            consumer.close();
        }

    }

    public void shutdown() {
        closed.set(true);
        consumer.wakeup();
    }

}
```

consumer.properties

```
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
session.timeout.ms=30000
key.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
value.deserializer=com.org.kafkaPro.PayDeserializer
enable.auto.commit=false
auto.offset.reset=earliest
group.id=test
isolation.level=read_committed
```

Appreciate your help..Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In your producer properties you are using `#transactional.id=1` (as you mentioned in question) in this you have mentioned `#` symbol. This might be creating issue.

If it is not the case than you can dump log segment of your topic and __transaction_state topic and from there you can debug easily what is going wrong.

Comment: I'm putting transactional id at run time if you see my code and then initializing kafka producer..otherwise it could have complained no transaction id found when i call producer.beginTransaction()..this issue is something else.

Comment: May I know your Kafka brokers are on which OS? If they are on windows than there is some issue.

Can you share your console debug logs for producers.

And share dump log segment. Use this command `kafka-run-class.bat kafka.tools.DumpLogSegments --files <.index , .log, and .timestamp>`

put flags like `--transaction-log-decoder` if you are dumping transaction_state topic logs. It would me more helpful for me to tell you the real issue.